# WooCommerce require registration to buy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to require a user registration before buying a product. Right now, when you add a product to the cart, then in the check out you can fill all the fields with your information but without a wordpress login. There is a simple option to create an account but is optional.

I'd like to know if is possible to modify the check out page to redirect a register page.

is it possible?

So if you wish to give any suggestion or any interesting link that will also be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 33):

In your site's admin go to WooCommerce>Settings>Checkout ex:

http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout

And make sure that "Enable guest checkout" is unchecked

[image]

**UPDATE for WooCommmerce 3.4+**

Pretty sure it was 3.4 when WooCommerce added it's privacy tools to help with GDPR compliance. This setting is now under

WooCommerce>Settings>Accounts&Privacy

or

`wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=account`

[image: Guest checkout options]

Comment: There is another step if you really want to lock down your checkout page and display the "You must be logged in to checkout" message.  Go to the Accounts tab and uncheck the "Enable Registration on the Checkout Page" option, as shown here:
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-remove-move-loginregistration-checkout/

Comment: This answer is out of date.   See below

Answer (score 1):

There are three rows in wp_options that I suggest you set for this [recommended value]:

- woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout [no]
- woocommerce_enable_signup_and_login_from_checkout [yes]
- woocommerce_enable_checkout_login_reminder [yes]

You can edit them in the admin console here:

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=account

[image]