# Is possible on wp to create automatic user after someone make an order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wp site and i use just this checkout fields

```
First name:
Last Name: 
Email:
Number:
Adress:
Other Information:
```

And i want to creat automatic user after someone make an order, is this possible?

Comment: This is probably better asked at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: They'll probably send it back since it is WooCommerce-specific.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Sidenote, pretty sure WooCommerce has a setting that requires users to create an account in order to checkout.

Comment: @helgatheviking is right
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747095/woocommerce-require-registration-to-buy]

Comment: Also, in the Accounts tab of Woocommerce admin settings, the checkbox labeled " Enable registration on the "Checkout" page " should be checked.