# how can we force customer to login or registration before checkout

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am make my  ecommerce website using wordpress and here is problem is when a non register or non login user  add product to  cart and then going to my cart page and click process to check out so it will take to me checkout page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce require registration to buy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747095/woocommerce-require-registration-to-buy)

Comment: In you admin panel at woocommerce setting in checkout tab you have to enable the Enable guest checkout is checked

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below code. it might be helpful for you.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
  wp_redirect( $location ); //$location = your login page url. 
}
```